# Foreach loop, but for first key do something else

Tags: php, foreach

Sorry if this is confusing. It's tough for me to put into words having beginner knowledge of PHP.

I'm using the following foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['technologies'] as $technologies){
    echo ", " . $technologies;
}
```

Which produces:

> , First, Second, Third

What I want:

> First, Second, Third

All I need is for the loop to skip the `echo ", "` for the first key. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Note that you're not validating the input in anyway.  This can lead to injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can pull out the indices of each array item using `=>` and not print a comma for the first item:

```
foreach ($_POST['technologies'] as $i => $technologies) {
    if ($i > 0) {
        echo ", ";
    }

    echo $technologies;
}
```

Or, even easier, you can use [**implode**($glue, $pieces)](http://www.php.net/implode), which "returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element":

```
echo implode(", ", $_POST['technologies']);
```

Comment: $_POST['technologies'] might not have numeric keys

Answer (score 5):

For general case of doing something in every but first iteration of foreach loop:

```
$first = true;
foreach ($_POST['technologies'] as $technologies){
    if(!$first) {
      echo ", ";
    } else {
      $first = false;
    }
    echo $technologies;
}
```

but [implode()](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is best way to deal with this specific problem of yours:

```
echo implode(", ", $_POST['technologies']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of a flag:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($_POST['technologies'] as $technologies){
  if($i > 1){
    echo ", " . $technologies;
  } else {
    echo $technologies;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer that deals with all types of arrays using whatever the first key of the array is:

```
# get the first key in array using the current iteration of array_keys (a.k.a first)
$firstKey = current(array_keys($array)); 

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    # if current $key !== $firstKey, prepend the ,
    echo ($key !== $firstKey ? ', ' : ''). $value;
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/tvgF4)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use PHP builtin function `implode()` to do this more easily and with less code?

Like this:

```
<?php
$a = ["first","second","third"];
echo implode($a, ", ");
```

So as per your case, simply do this:

```
echo implode($_POST['technologies'], ", ");
```